# How to disable all authorization atributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, .net-core

Im using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` to authenticate and authorize in my ASP.NET Core project. I implemented feew methods looking like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = UserRoles.Admin)]
public IActionResult GetIds(string name)
{
...
}
```

Now i want to test all methods and of course in my unit test i need to be log in to test it. I don't want to do it all time, so i wonder, if there is any possiblity to disable or ignore all those authorize attributes onyl during tests. For example i set field "tests" in my appsettings.json as true, and all attributes will be ignored.

This option will not be using only during tests. After finish product will be certificated. Certyfication system can use only URLs and not be able to log in.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you write unit tests for `Controller` class, you need directly test its public methods => directly call `YourController.GetIds()` method in your case:

```
var expectedResult = ... // setup expected result
var controller = new YourController();
var result = controller.GetIds(testName);

Assert.AreEqual(result, expectedResult);
```

While you call method directly, attributes like `[Authorize]` do not participate in method execution.

If you write a functional test, then you need to think about creating the test user, that will have appropriate rights to call this endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, it is a valuable tip. But it will work only temporarily for me. this product must be certificated. Certyfing system will use only URLs and not be able to log in (specyfication of it, no my idea). So the best option for my will be set properties in config file and turn authorization off. I will update question.